# Python+Memcache changing array to string

Tags: python, arrays, memcached

I am using Amazon Elasticache and pythons `pymemcache` module.

```
client = Client(('xxxx', 11211))
test=[1,2,3,4]
client.set('test_key', test)
result = client.get('test_key')

pprint.pprint(result)
pprint.pprint(test)
```

This outputs the following:

```
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

AS you can see, the memcache result has been changed to a string. How can I store an array? Or convert the string back to an array?

Answer (score 3):

Memcache itself stores values as strings. You can [customize your serialization](http://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#serialization) in `pymemcache` if needed. It looks like by [default](http://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/pymemcache.client.base.html#pymemcache.client.base.Client), `pymemcache` just uses the `__str__` method on the value if a serializer is not provided:

> Values must have a **str**() method to convert themselves to a byte
>   string. Unicode objects can be a problem since str() on a Unicode
>   object will attempt to encode it as ASCII (which will fail if the
>   value contains code points larger than U+127). You can fix this with a
>   serializer or by just calling encode on the string (using UTF-8, for
>   instance).
>
> If you intend to use anything but str as a value, it is a good idea to
>   use a serializer and deserializer. The pymemcache.serde library has
>   some already implemented serializers, including one that is compatible
>   with the python-memcache library.

I personally prefer [`pylibmc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibmc) to pymemcache. It handles non-string values quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The service [memcached](https://memcached.org/) that pymemcache is a client for only supports string values. This is why by default pymemcache returns a string. 
I suggest adding a small wrapper to serialize and deserialize your values from strings to objects, like arrays. The client supports adding your own serializer, like so

```
import json
from pymemcache.client.base import Client

def json_serializer(key, value):
    if type(value) == str:
        return value, 1
    return json.dumps(value), 2

def json_deserializer(key, value, flags):
    if flags == 1:
        return value
    if flags == 2:
        return json.loads(value)
    raise Exception("Unknown serialization format")

client = Client(('localhost', 11211), serializer=json_serializer,
            deserializer=json_deserializer)
client.set('key', [1,2,3,4])
result = client.get('key')
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the library wants you to serialise your data first.
https://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#serialization

Maybe you could use an alternative library?
https://github.com/pinterest/pymemcache#comparison-with-other-libraries

I'm not sure if it suits your purposes, but [dogpile.cache](https://dogpilecache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might also be worth checking out. It's great to work with and it has memcached as one of its backends.